# apply Window.partitionBy for two columns to get n-core dataset in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, group-by, count, window-functions

I have a data set of 2M entries with user,item,rating information. I want to filter out data so that it includes items that are rated by at least 2 users and users that rated at least 2 items. I can get one constraint done using a window function but not sure how to get both done.

input:

| user | product | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| J | p1 | 3 |
| J | p2 | 4 |
| M | p1 | 4 |
| M | p3 | 3 |
| B | p2 | 3 |
| B | p4 | 3 |
| B | p3 | 3 |
| N | p3 | 2 |
| N | p5 | 4 |

here is sample data.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
# Create Spark Context
sc = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]")\
     .config("spark.jars.packages", "org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2")\
     .getOrCreate()

sampleData = (("J", "p1", 3), \
    ("J", "p2", 4),  \
    ("M", "p1", 4),   \
    ("M", "p3", 3),  \
    ("B", "p2", 3),  \
    ("B", "p4", 3),  \
    ("B", "p3", 3),  \
    ("N", "p3", 2),\
    ("N", "p5", 4) \
  )
 
columns= ["user", "product", "rating"]

df = sc.createDataFrame(data = sampleData, schema = columns)
```

desired output is,

| user | product | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| J | p1 | 3 |
| J | p2 | 4 |
| M | p1 | 4 |
| M | p3 | 3 |
| B | p2 | 3 |
| B | p3 | 3 |

window function I used to fulfill "users that rated at least 2 items"  is

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import  count, col
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.partitionBy("user")

df.withColumn("count", F.count("rating").over(window))\
    .filter(F.col("count") >= 2).drop("count")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the below?

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = sampleData, schema = columns)
df_p = df.groupBy('product').count().filter('count >= 2').select('product')
df = df.join(df_p, ['product'], 'inner')
df_u = df.select('user').groupBy('user').count().filter('count >= 
2').select('user')
df = df.join(df_u, ['user'], 'inner')
```

Gives below output:

| user | product | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | p2 | 3 |
| B | p3 | 3 |
| M | p1 | 4 |
| M | p3 | 3 |
| J | p2 | 4 |
| J | p1 | 3 |

Comment: @krishthw I see you retracted the answer. Does this not solve some other case that you wanted?

Comment: Oh sorry. It works! I would be glad if I can use window function. Anyway, I can accept yours!. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with two window functions. I am less familiar with the df syntax, here is the sql:

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("ratings")

spark.sql("""
SELECT USER,
       product,
       rating,
       Count(*)OVER (partition BY USER )    num_ratings_for_user,
       Count(*)OVER (partition BY product ) num_raters_for_product
FROM   ratings 
""")
```

You can filter over this.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window1 = Window.partitionBy("user")
window2 = Window.partitionBy("product")

df.withColumn("count_users", F.count("rating").over(window1))\
  .filter(F.col("count_users") >= 2)\
  .withColumn("count_prod", F.count("rating").over(window2))\
  .filter(F.col("count_prod") >= 2)\
  .drop("count", "count_users", "count_prod")\
  .show()
```

User N has rated more than 1 product so the output should be:

```
+----+-------+------+
|user|product|rating|
+----+-------+------+
|   J|     p1|     3|
|   M|     p1|     4|
|   B|     p2|     3|
|   J|     p2|     4|
|   B|     p3|     3|
|   M|     p3|     3|
|   N|     p3|     2|
+----+-------+------+
```

Comment: N should not be in the output. if N is there, both constraints won't satisfy.

Comment: "I want to filter out data so that it includes items that are rated by at least 2 users and users that rated at least 2 items"

N rated 2 items and P3 was rated by more than 2 users

Comment: @ Luiz Viola, yes filtered data set should satisfy those two constraints. not the input. That' s why i include "... so that it includes" I am sorry if my wording confused you. thank you for your effort!

Comment: @ Luiz Viola, It would be great to have the desired output with the window function if you are familiar with it. thanks

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Reading your requirement it makes sense to consider N - P3. I don't know exactly how you want it to be handled by a window function